# A combinatorial identity for $\sum_{k=0}^i \binom{n}{k}$?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Is there a combinatorial identity for the following:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{i}\binom{n}{k} $$ for arbitrary integers $n, i$ with $n > i$? If so, what is this identity called?

Comment: Alas, no, except for special values of $i$.

Comment: These are values like $n$, $n/2$, yes?

Comment: Right, and also silly things like $0,1,2,3$.

Answer (score 3):

Using a CAS, I found this "nice" expression $$\sum_{k=0}^{i}\binom{n}{k}=2^n-\binom{n}{i+1} \, _2F_1(1,i-n+1;i+2;-1) $$ May I suggest we name it, at least for the time being, Ayesha's identity.

Comment: Ha. That is a great name.

Comment: @Ayesha. This is my pleasure and my gift to you for today !